# stop angular.js from rewriting "+" to "%2B" in url

Tags: angularjs

Angular quietly rewrites urls, but this specific case is causing problems for my app. Where would I look if I were trying to patch this particular case in angular?

Will it break a lot of stuff to force angular to behave this way?

Comment: Note: There's a reason it's getting escaped.  `+` is typically interpreted as a space in URLs.

Comment: yes. I'm aware of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the fix from the answer above, all I had to do was go to this line
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L873

and add a

```
replace(/%2B/gi, '+').
```

to the chain. Worked a treat! Thanks @fastreload!!!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Directly from source:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L854</strike>

Either recompile it, or just find the relevant part in your version of angularjs and change it.

It is caused by `encodeURIComponent` which is a native function. The way it is implemented by the browser is possibly standardized. It converts `+` to `%2B` along with many others.

You should then change your app's behavior.

Comment: Though it may be better if you change your applications behavior, less specifity/customization across systems is always better.

Comment: I saw that earlier too, that does does the reverse of what I want ... i.e it actually takes "%2B" and turns it into "+" for angular's purposes, I want it to stop taking "+" and turning it into "%2B" after the page has loaded

Comment: Thanks that helped me figure it out!